# JQUERY: alerta cuando se cambia un checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero hacer una lista de actividades donde cada input tenga un valor en tiempo, es decir numérico, y cada vez que seleccione uno me salte una alerta, pero parece que no me funciona

```
<div id="contenedorCheckBox">
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="240"> Factoría
        (240 mins)</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="270" >
        (270 mins)</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="180"> Cómo
       (180 mins)</p>

</div>
```

y este es el script del código:

```
 $('#btnActividades').click(function() {

        $('#formulario').remove()
        $("#titulo").empty()
        $("#titulo").append("Tiempo disponible: ")
        $("#canjeador").append(function() {

            return '<div id="contenedorCheckBox"> <p><input type="checkbox" value="240"> Factoría Digital: Industria 4.0 (240 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="270" > Transformación Digital - ERP Inteligente (270 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="180"> Cómo Potenciar el Liderazgo (180 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="225"> Encuentro de empresas andaluzas (225 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox"  value="240"> Oportunidades del Entorno Digital (240 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="240" > Costes transporte marítimo internacional (240 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox"  value="120" > FP Sector Aeroespacial (120 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox"  value="180"> Presentación Tactiómetro 2019 (180 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox"value="180" > Gemelo Digital (180 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="90" > Cómo ganar dinero con tu blog y redes (90 mins)</p> </div>'


        });

        //Recorre cada checkbox resta al contador
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').on('change', function() {
            alert("Pruebas")
        });


    });
```

Comment: Hola. No es muy buena idea estar lanzando alerts, cuando no sean estrictamente necesarios. Algunos navegadores chillan cuando vas por el segundo o tercero y te piden permiso de mostrarlos, y si por casualidad te equivocas, te desactivan los mensajes emergentes de la página (y luego te ves a gatas para reactivarlos). Usa un elemento dentro de la página para mostrar esos datos, y limpialo cuando le hagas click.

Answer (score 1):

Remueve el atributo `checked` del selector `input[type=checkbox]`:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
       alert("Pruebas")
 });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox"  value="100"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
//Recorre cada checkbox resta al contador
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e) {
    // seleccionamos el elemento clickeado
    self = $(this);
    // validamos que este checked
    if(self.is(':checked'))
       alert(`${self.val()} is checked`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedorCheckBox">
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="240"> Factoría
        (240 mins)</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="270" >
        (270 mins)</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="180"> Cómo
       (180 mins)</p>

</div>
```